# Rails 4 : ajax error not captured when using form_for w remote: true datatype :son

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, http-error

I have a form (#new_group) written as :

```
   <%= form_for @group, remote: true, html: {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'group', class: 'form-horizontal', id: "new_group"} do |f| %>
```

I setup all ajax calls to be :json datatype

```
  //Default to JSON responses for remote calls
  $.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
  })
```

submitting the form , it's correctly processed as :son

```
            def create
          @group =  Group.new(group_params)
          respond_to do |format|
            if @group.save
              format.html {  ... }
              format.json { ... }
            else 
              format.html { ... }
              format.json { 
                errors = {errors: @group.errors.full_messages}
                byebug
                render(json: errors.to_json, status: :unprocessable_entity )
              }
            end
          end

         debugging :
         (byebug) errors.inspect
         {:errors=>["Group already defined"]}
```

but then I can read in the console :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/groups 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/groups"
```

Why the 422 http error is not captures as an ajax:error event ? 
I wrote :

```
        $("#new_group")
            .on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
              console.log("new group added!");
            })
            .on("ajax:error", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
              console.log("ERROR: " + status);
            errors = xhr.responseJSON.error;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 w turbolinks , I have to write :

```
      $(document).on('ajax:success', '#new_group', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      });

      $(document).on('ajax:error', '#new_group', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        //console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        errors = data.responseJSON.errors; 
        $.each( errors, function( key, message ) {
          $("#modalGroupAlert ul").append( '<li>' + message + '</li>' );
        });
        $( "#modalGroupAlert" ).show();
      });
```